# Zend fw, custom validation errors

Tags: validation, zend-framework, forms

I am creating a website with Zend_Form. In my controller, I assign a form object to the view. In the view, I use the following code to render the form:

```
<?php if ( isset( $this->success ) ): ?>
    <div class="message success"><p>Thanks!</p></div>
<?php elseif ( sizeof( $this->form->getMessages( ) ) > 0 ): ?>
    <div class="message success"><p>Something went wrong..</p></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<form>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <?php echo $this->form->name; ?>

    <label>E-mail:</label>
    <?php echo $this->form->name; ?>
</form>
```

Until now, this way of checking if there were form errors was good enough. But my client asked me if I could also specify the field that was not correct. So, for example: "Warning: you forgot to fill in your name". I've really got no idea on how to do this with Zend. Does anybody know where to start?

Thanks,

Martijn

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see it by requesting getErrors(); on the Zend_Form object.

It will return a array of errors where the key is the field name 
returns something like this.

```
array(
 'fieldname' => array('error1', 'error2'),
 'username' => array('errors')
);
```

You could also call $form->getElements() and iterate over each element to see which one is throwing errors

Comment: That's true, but the problem is that my field names are English and my website is in Dutch. It would be really user unfriendly to show these English field names.

Comment: Yes the field names are the name="" value's of the inputs / selects / textarea, you have to either add custom errors to the elements (which are in dutch) or create a conditional logic within the view saying something like "if ($fieldname == 'username') { echo "error on dutch" }" You can also add a Zend_Translate object to the form for handling error translations.

Comment: I did try to use a Zend_Translate adapter to provide translated error messages. This worked, but this only provides a way to translate the messages itself (e.g. "This field is empty" => "Dit veld is leeg"), but it doesn't provide a way to also add a name for the field?

Comment: You could iterate all the elements and call $element->isValid() to check them, and then use $element->getLabel() . ": " . implode("," $element->getErrorMessages()); . Or else you could use customize the standard decorators.